# Session Value Not Working

Tags: php, forms, post, submit

I was trying to make a one page script with the action set to server php self but when running the script even after I type in the right password I am given "You Must Supply a Password". Am I doing this right. Please let me know my mistake

login.php

```
    <?php
        $pass = 'defense6';

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            if(($_POST['password'] == $pass)) {    
                   $_SESSION['password'] = md5($_POST['password']);
                   header('Location: index.php');
            } else {
                echo 'Password Invalid';
            }

        }
        else {
            echo 'You must supply a password.'.$_SESSION['password'] ;
        }
        ?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">  
Password: &nbsp;<input name="password" type="password" /><br/><br/>
:
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" style="float:right;" />

<br/>
  <p></p>
</form>
```

index.php

```
<?php
$pass = 'defense6';
 if($_SESSION['password'] == md5($pass)) {}
else {header('Location: login.php');}
?>
```

Comment: What is `$_POST['submit']`? Because *that* is the if statement that is failing if you're seeing `"You Must Supply a Password"`. You need to learn some basic debugging skills and figure out how program flow proceeds through your script. Try inspecting `var_dump($_POST)`.

Comment: Are you calling [session_start()](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) in the beginning of all files that use session vars?

Comment: Sorry meagar but what was happening was the form was submitting and redirected to the index but their was no session_start so it redirected back to login and appeared with no post['submit']

Comment: It actually has everything the form did find a submit then redirected to the index. Since their was no session_start the code said else {header('Location: login.php');}. Then after redirecting the page didn't any longer have the post data and gave an error.

Comment: don't check for a post by looking for a form field. it's unreliable. use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'`. That's 100% reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `seesion_start()` on every page you use session.

[`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

Comment: you can also set the http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start session auto start in the php.ini

Answer (score 1):

Add [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) at the beginning of the pages that will help to maintain the session across requests.

Comment: Wow cant beleive I missed this. Thanks for pointing out my bug.